# Aborted the task because of a task failure or a concurrent HA_RESTORE_DB request. while restored S3 to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, database-restore

I have uploaded the backup file to S3 using CLI I am

I am getting an error while restoring the database from amazon s3

I have using below commands to restore the database

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database
@restore_db_Name = 'DatabaseName',
@s3_arn_to_restore_from = 'arn:aws:s3://bucketname/backupfilename.bak'
```

I am getting below error in the status

Aborted the task because of a task failure or a concurrent HA_RESTORE_DB request has been aborted Could not parse the amazon Task has been aborted  Access Denied

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your ARN is malformed. Example from [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Native.Using.Restore):

```
@s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/file_name.extension'
```